# For each through List<string> returned from AJAX GET in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

The problem is as the title describes... I'm trying to loop through the values in a list of strings and alert them on the page.  Unfortunately, I keep getting an error of...

> "**Uncaught TypeError: response.forEach is not a function**"

I've read a few other places on SO about for loops in javascript, but it seems that it works with arrays.  I'll state that I'm a novice when it comes to JavaScript... so is there an equivalent .ToArray() method in JavaScript?  I've written a simple application to show what it is I'm trying to accomplish.

**Note**: I'm unable to change the return type of the controller method "GetStringList". In the larger application, the method must return a list of strings.

---

**Controller Method (C#)**

```
    public List<string> GetStringList(){
        List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();

        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connection_String);

        sqlConn.Open();

        string sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM dbo.[SampleOrders] WHERE Active = 1";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, sqlConn);
        SqlDataReader sqlDR = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (sqlDR.HasRows) {
            while (sqlDR.Read()) {
                listOfStrings.Add((string)sqlDR["SalesOrder"]);
            }
        }

        sqlDR.Close();
        sqlCmd.Dispose();
        sqlConn.Close();

        return listOfStrings;
    }
```

---

**View / JavaScript Function**

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#demoBtn').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/Home/GetStringList',
                    success: function (response) {
                        response.forEach(function (item) {
                            alert(item);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Please let me know if any clarifications need made -- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just return `listOfStrings` as it would just print something like `System.Collections.Generic.List 1[System.String]`

So you should change your code to something like:

```
return string.Join(",",listOfStrings);
```

But, since you want to traverse it using Javascript, I suggest returning it as a JSON, doing this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfStrings);
```

This way, you'll end up with an string similar to:

```
["string1","string2","string3"]
```

Now, you may change your jQuery so it expects a JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json', //So your response will be parsed and ready to use as a Javascript object
  url: '/Home/GetStringList',
  success: function (response) {
    response.forEach(function (item) {
      alert(item);
    });
  }
});
```

If you absolutely don't want to change the return statement of the function, you have two options:

- Use an optional parameter so you can tell when you need a JSON

```
public List<string> GetStringList(bool json = False){
  ...
  if(json){
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfStrings);
  }
  return listOfStrings;
}
```

- Create another method to wrap the return, like so:

```
public string GetStringListAsJSON(){
  return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetStringList());
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify what you're saying...  There's no other way than changing my return statement in the GetStringsList controller method?  I don't want to change the return statement since other things within' the controller rely on this method returning a List<String>.  I thought about creating an entirely separate method to do something like you've described... but then I've duplicated code processes and was wondering if there was any way to avoid that by being able to return a C# List<String> to javascript and converting it to an array on the client.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I edited my answer to give you two ways of changing the return statement without actually damaging other things

Comment: Alright, so it's an unavoidable situation.  Thank you very much for clearing that up and providing a variety of examples.  I've implemented it and it's working as intended.

Answer (score 2):

`.forEach()` is an array method. `response` is the XMLHttpRequest response string. Since there is no `List<String>` type in JavaScript, you just have a big string.

You should try parsing that string into an Array (if that's the structure you've received) with `var myArray = JSON.parse(response)` and then you'd be able to call `.forEach()` on `myArray`.

Have you actually logged `response` to see the exact syntax you are getting?

Comment: I have... I've gotten "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]".  When I try to get the value it says undefined.

Comment: You get `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` from JavaScript that logs `response`?

Comment: Correct - I did an alert(response) after the success function and it alerted "System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]".  Am I misunderstanding what you mean by log?  Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: In your browser, press F12. This will open the developer tools. Click to the tab marked "Console". Whenever you need to know the value of something, write `console.log(something)` and this is where you will see it. If you click the "Network" tab, you can see your requests and responses. The fact that you are seeing the .NET type and not an actual value tells me that your WebMethod isn't returning the correct data.

Comment: Yeah, it's still returning the same result.  When I change the GetStringList method to return a JsonResult and change the method return to Json(listOfStrings, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)... It then logs the information I want in the console.  But, I'd like to return a List<string>.